# How to extract specific contents from a text file

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to extract the data from text.My Text file is as below:

```
Sampath Shanbhag 8th Semester Undergraduate | Computer Science Engineering | UCE RTU, Kota =91 90085258893 | sampathshanbhag78@gmail.com | abcd address SUMMARY To seek an opportunity to apply my technologies expertise along with my creative problem solving skills in an innovative software Company. Experience - Machine Learning Engineering Intern, xyz Industry , Bangalore (May 2017 - June 2018) Leaned the foundation concept of Machine Learning. - Software Engineering Intern , abcd Company (July 2014- may 2015) Developed and Optimized several Projects including eccomerce, booking & Reservation, non-profit organizational website etc. Skills : Python, php, sql, nodejs, java.
```

I am trying to extract Experience from this. How can I achieve this?

```
with open('E:/cvparser/sampath.txt', 'r', encoding = 'utf-8') as f:
    exp_summary_flag = False
    exp_summary = ''
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith('EXPERIENCE'):
            exp_summary_flag = True
        elif exp_summary_flag:
            exp_summary += line
            if not line.strip(): break

print(exp_summary)
```

The above code returns blank space.

Expected Output:

```
Experience
- Machine Learning Engineering Intern, xyz Industry , Bangalore (May 2017 - June 2018) Leaned the foundation concept of Machine Learning.
- Software Engineering Intern , abcd Company (July 2014- may 2015) Developed and Optimized several Projects including eccomerce, booking & Reservation, non-profit organizational website etc
```

Comment: please confirm `text.My` contains only one line as mentioned in the question

Comment: if your input is just a 1-liner string `s`, then `experience = s[s.lower().index('experience - '):]` - but this is a pretty specific solution...

Comment: It will help if you will format the example as the actual file you are reading as in your example it seems like there is NOT any line starting with EXPERIENCE... Now thinking about it , your problem might be that you are searching for all-caps. Try changing to `if line.lower().startswith('experience'):`

Comment: Actually I'm working on resumes and trying to extract data from it. So I used pdfminer to convert pdf files to text and then extract data. But when I convert the pdf to Text format, after conversion the file looks as above. can someone please show me in general, how to extract Experience field from pdf file?